# Bootstrap popover function issues

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two button for trigger their own popover window, once you click on it, it shows the popover, also you can see the + symbol on the button becomes - symbol. I need a function that allows:

1. By clicking  anywhere on the screen, the popover closes and the - symbol becomes + symbol.
2. By clicking the button again, the popover closes and the - symbol becomes + symbol.
3. By clicking the other button, the popover closes and the - symbol becomes + symbol, also the other button's + symbol becomes - symbol, and it's own popover window popsup

Hope you guys can give me some idea, I will appreciate!

This is my current jquery code:

```
function change() {
    $(".consistbtn").each(function (index) {
//.consistbtn is the class of the link button you see.
        $("#popover" + index).click(function (e) {
//#popover+index is the unique id for the button 
            $("#swpimg" + index + ">img").toggle();
//#swpimg is the div id wraped  + and - as imgs.
        })
    });
}
$(function () {
    $(".consistbtn").popover({
        trigger: 'focus',
        html: true
    });
    $(".consistbtn").on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".pop_on").show();
        $(this).parent().find(".pop_off").hide();

    });
    $(".consistbtn").on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".pop_on").hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".pop_off").show();
    });
})
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.pop_off').hide();
    $('.pop_on').show();
});
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle??

Comment: try this : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover_focus&stacked=h

Comment: as @GuruprasadRao already stated, provide a fiddle or a bootply and we will gladly be able to help. or at least post the corresponding html code, so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To make the show-and-hide-functionality behave as you want, simply set the `trigger`-property of your popover to `"focus"`. To make it disappear onClick, you could a one time click handler on the clicked button in the shown event which makes it lose focus (e.g. by calling `blur()` on it). Take care that it does not get fired in case the button gets clicked after it already lost focus by some other action (clicking another button or sth.).

As for the icons: attach event handlers to your popovers and add/remove the corresponding classes like in the following example (this one is using fa):

**EXAMPLE**

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('.btn-po-pm').popover({  // trigger popover on focus realizes most of what you want.
      trigger: "focus",
      placement: "top"
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() { 
    $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus'); // switch icon-classes
    $('.btn-po-pm').unbind('click');  // remove old click handlers
    $(this).one('click', function(e) {
      $(this).blur(); // make element lose focus (this triggers the popovers hide-event)
    });
  }).on('hidden.bs.popover', function() { 
    $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');  // switch icon-classes
  }).focusout(function(){
    $('.btn-po-pm').unbind('click'); // remove one time click handler on lose focus, to prevent show-and-close immediately
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h1>Popover sample</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-po-pm" data-toggle="popover" data-content="The one popover"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> The one</button> 
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-po-pm" data-toggle="popover" data-content="The other popover"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> The other one</button>
```

Comment: Very appreciate your answer!  But like in this situation: you click "the one" button, popover displays, and + becomes -, which is exactly I want, a bit more needed is if you want to close its popover, click "the one" button again, the popover should be closed, do you have any idea about this problem? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: now i got it (needed to sleep one more time). see edit.

Comment: you might be able to shorten this, but you get the idea and it behaves as you desire i guess

Comment: Thank you so much! Your idea is very straight forward to get this issue fixed! I did some research online, there is an other way to reach it as well, I 'm more than happy to share with you and others, if you guys needed:

Comment: go search "bootstrapx-clickover" js file,  this is another plug-in function to improve the bootstrap popover. my js would be looks like this:

Comment: $('[rel="clickover1"]').clickover({
//[rel="clickover1"] is to find the popover buttons
        onShown: function () { //onShown is the plugin function to do sth when popover on showing
            $('[rel="clickover1"]').children('i').addClass('minus');
        },
        onHidden: function () {
            $('[rel="clickover1"]').children('i').removeClass('minus');
        }
    });
if you have multi-popovers, could loop the above function in the for loop,  just simply add an index to distinguish each other.